# Function called multiple times during Vue component render

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a component inside a route-view which is in turn part of another route-view so the tree is like this:

```
<app>
  <appContainer>  // This is a route-view
    <myView> // Also a route-view
      <myComponent>
```

In `myComponent` I have this conditional rendering:

```
<b-button v-if="isAdmin(currentUser)'">
```

This function is exhibiting unexpected behaviors

```
isAdmin(username) {
  let userObject = this.$store.getters.getCurrentUserObject(username)
  return userObject.role === 'ADMIN'
}
```

The `userObject` was turning up as `undefined` until I added a debugger inside the function and realized that this it's being called multiple times during page rendering some of which the store `data` property is still empty resulting in `getters` returning `null`. What could be the reason? Why is this method called multiple times?
PS: I have a for loop in the component, could this be the reason?

```
<div v-for="bike in bikes":key="bike.timestamp">
  <p>{{ bike.name }}</p>
  <b-img fluid v-if="bike.imagePath" v-bind:src="returnImage(bike.imagePath)"></b-img>
  <p>{{ bike.timestamp}}</p>
</div>
```

This is called in the `created` hook

```
created() { 
   this.getBikes()
 }
```

Comment: If there's anything async involved this is expected behavior--things render when things change, and barring a synchronous process, you need to be able to handle data not being set or percolating through the system yet.

Comment: There are no explicit async operations on the frontend (only backend) though make calls using Axios not sure if that counts.

Comment: Yes, that counts.  Ajax calls are asynchronous.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a return type issue at first sight.

`isAdmin` is already returning a boolean which in turn is getting “explicitly” compared to `currentUser`. The result of such comparison is always falsy.

You gotta change the `v-if` directive’s condition to something like:

```
v-if="isAdmin(currentUser)"
```

Regarding the multiple calls, you gotta update your question to reflect the details of the loop you’ve mentioned.

Comment: You're right about the return and I've modified accordingly but the underlying problem persists.

Comment: @Samuel Your update to the question is not helpful at all. Please consider putting the whole component code there; only remove the unnecessary irrelevant parts.

Answer (score 0):

`PS: I have a for loop in the component, could this be the reason?`
Probably it's the reason because it renders many times as the loop determine.

Provide your code of the loop to have more information to debug.

Comment: I'm not sure how that would be helpful, it's a normal `v-for` loop.

Comment: @Samuel We have no way of knowing how the for loop interacts with the code you've shown. If the component loops over the call then obviously it'll be called multiple times.

Comment: Definitely, the loop doesn't affect the function `isAdmin`. As a workaround you can try `v-if="currentUser && isAdmin(currentUser)"` to call the function only when `currentUser` is available.